# How to control the position of unbreakable long equation in double column latex using strip?

Tags: equations, pdftex

I want to position the long equation at the top or at the bottom of the page. How can I do that

```
        \begin{strip}
        \begin{align}
    Very long equation.
        \end{align}
    \end{strip}
```

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you provided a small complete test document. You could use `figure*` or `\twocolumn[ ... equation ...]...` instead of `strip` to put a spanning equation at the top of the page

Comment: Thank you, I used figure*

Answer (score 1):

You could use `figure*` or `\twocolumn[ ... equation ...]...` instead of `strip` to get a spanning area at the top of the page.